# conditional structure of multiple possible argument combinations in python

Tags: python

whats a good way to check for multiple optional arguments in python w argparse? E.g 'if x and y but not z, if x and z but not y, if y and z but not x' etc?
making this bot thingy that just waits for a string (polling upon a message event), and want to be able to supply, optionally, a user, server, or channel in which to wait for the string... if the user supplies a server but no channel, then it means we want to check all messages from all channels in the server... if both channel and server, then we check only messages from that server AND in that channel... not sure how to program this without very many branches of (likely duplicate) code.

The end result being, that we send a message when we find our text. But that we only find the text at the 'highest' level of specificity provided. How do I write this out as conditional statements?

Edit: Example:

```
async def on_msg(msg):
    if args.text in msg.content and msg.guild.id == args.server and msg.channel.id == args.channel and msg.author.id == args.author:
        await msg.channel.send('test')
```

This only works when all options are set, but I would like to have the ability to omit options, e.g:

```
async def on_msg(msg):
    if args.text in msg.content or msg.guild.id == args.server or msg.channel.id == args.channel or msg.author.id == args.author:
            await msg.channel.send('test')
```

But this will not do what I want, because the user could omit ANY of the terms, so long as one is true. I'd like to USE whichever values were provided to choke down the level of specificity, not merely either/or...

Ideally, I would want to have something like this:

```
async def on_msg(msg, channel, server, user):
```

Which would let me control where to look for my text. But this doesn't exist in the API (discord.py) to my knowledge.

Comment: provide defalt values for argparse.. like set your varaibles to some -999 or some thing and then just check which value was provided and which were not .

Comment: please show us some example code so that we can modify it to your needs and test it.

Comment: Keen on sharing what you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

add args like

```
arg_parser.add_argument("--first", type=float, help="first value", default=1)
arg_parser.add_argument("--second", type=float, help="second value", default=2)
arg_parser.add_argument("--third", type=float, help="third value", default=3)
```

and then call like

```
python <PythonFileName.py> --first=<first input> --second=<second input> --third=<third input>
```